# How to fix "m=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0" issue to enabling surround sound streaming (5.1 and 7.1 channel)

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, audio-streaming, opus, surround

I am creating a streaming application with surround sound audio support, currently stereo is supported and streaming is working. Codec - `Opus`, Browser - `Google Chrome`

When I give offer SDP to browser it return me with `m=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0` then I munge this resulting SDP from browser with following changes (also this is what I pass in offer sdp from server to browser).

**For 7.1 channel**

```
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111\r\n
a=rtpmap:111 multiopus/48000/8\r\n
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\n
a=fmtp:111 channel_mapping=0,6,1,2,3,4,5,7;num_streams=8;coupled_streams=0;maxaveragebitrate=510000;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\n
```

**For 5.1 channel**

```
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111\r\n
a=rtpmap:111 multiopus/48000/6\r\n
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\n
a=fmtp:111 a=fmtp:111 channel_mapping=0,4,1,2,3,5;num_streams=4;coupled_streams=2;maxaveragebitrate=510000;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\n
```

*But at the end audio streaming doesn't work !!!*

---

**Offer Sdp from server**

```
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
m=audio 47998 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:47998 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2122260223 10.40.102.152 47998 typ host
a=mid:0
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=sendonly
a=msid:second_stream_id audio
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:111 multiopus/48000/8
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 channel_mapping=0,6,1,2,3,4,5,7;num_streams=8;coupled_streams=0;maxaveragebitrate=510000;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=ptime:10
a=ssrc:1 cname:odrerir
m=video 47998 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 101 102 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:47998 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2122260223 10.40.102.152 47998 typ host
a=mid:1
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=sendonly
a=msid:stream_id fbc-video-0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
...
```

**Processed Sdp from browser** after it pass through function `setRemoteDescription`

```
a=group:BUNDLE 1 2
m=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:HSRB
a=ice-pwd:xzh/4T2ENxA4tO4mUMlTN42s
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5A:71:54:A8:A4:82:58:AD:1E:73:7B:65:2E:FC:D6:E0:CA:47:76:D1:FA:B9:33:F4:90:FE:77:74:64:C5:08:02
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc:3852651172 cname:4sZE5ap0JbPq4Is1
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 101 102 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:Z8bB
a=ice-pwd:hOiAOMEYMZlPVLZYrcvQCIH6
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5A:71:54:A8:A4:82:58:AD:1E:73:7B:65:2E:FC:D6:E0:CA:47:76:D1:FA:B9:33:F4:90:FE:77:74:64:C5:08:02
a=setup:active
a=mid:1
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
...
```

**Munge Sdp that we send again to browser**

```
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:Z8bB
a=ice-pwd:hOiAOMEYMZlPVLZYrcvQCIH6
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5A:71:54:A8:A4:82:58:AD:1E:73:7B:65:2E:FC:D6:E0:CA:47:76:D1:FA:B9:33:F4:90:FE:77:74:64:C5:08:02
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 multiopus/48000/8
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 channel_mapping=0,6,1,2,3,4,5,7;num_streams=8;coupled_streams=0;maxaveragebitrate=510000;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=ssrc:3852651172 cname:4sZE5ap0JbPq4Is1
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 101 102 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:19440
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:Z8bB
a=ice-pwd:hOiAOMEYMZlPVLZYrcvQCIH6
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5A:71:54:A8:A4:82:58:AD:1E:73:7B:65:2E:FC:D6:E0:CA:47:76:D1:FA:B9:33:F4:90:FE:77:74:64:C5:08:02
a=setup:active
a=mid:1
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
...
```

I did notice that on setRemoteDesription callback passed sdp has additional ice-username/password

```
a=ice-ufrag:Z8bB
a=ice-pwd:hOiAOMEYMZlPVLZYrcvQCIH6
```

which are not the ones I got from server.

Comment: I debugged into chrome log and following seemed to be the flagged logs from webrtc
[warning:audio_send_stream.cc(876)] Config is invalid: min_bitrate_bps=-1; max_bitrate_bps=-1; both expected greater or equal to 0
[warning:rtp_transport.cc(196)] Failed to demux RTP packet: PT=111 SSRC=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group id bundle doesn't contain the mid of audio stream after processing from browser. Thus the surround streaming doesn't works.

```
Processed Sdp from browser
a=group:BUNDLE 1 2        <--- Real issue
```

**## A little explanation :-**

- Chrome browser is expected to reject the audio stream as multiopus is not supported, and when you go through the chrome_debug logs it states that only supported audio format is opus/48000/2
- Thus chrome browser return with port 0 in case of audio([RFC 3264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264#section-5.1))
- But when we again munge the sdp then browser follows the multiopus path which is an extension to libwebrtc and streaming works.

**Q. How I arrive at group id solution?**

- Chrome debug log help me that something with mid 0 is arrived but it is not able to demux those packets
- `Failed to demux RTP packet: PT=111 SSRC=1` ([Reference](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup/issues/360))
- All the streams in a webrtc transport are bundled and to identify each stream we pass on mid and inside group bundle we pass high level information related to what streams we will be sending

> Please fill in the missing information, as there are very least
> resources around surround sound streaming. This may help developers
> working in the similar domain :)